# Can I use google maps API in my own website and link it to android app?

Tags: php, android

I have written an android app that takes picture through camera intent, save the picture on sd card, detect user location through GPS and makes an overlay of the picture on google map. Now I want to make a web server to store the images and their information i.e. location on map, there and display the overlays on google map on my website. can I use the google map API in my own website and make overlays ? I want to use php for the site development. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Google API for Overlay open this link [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

Answer (score 1):

> can I use the google map API in my own website and make overlays ?

Yes you most certainly can.

[see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)